# Cropping a transparent hole in an UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to create a hole within an UIImage, but it must be a transparent hole. This whole will be placed right in the middle of a sprite, but for the sake of testing, I am creating a whole in the upper left corner:

[image]

I accomplished this by:

```
    let hole = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.addRect(hole)
    context.clip(using: .evenOdd)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context.fill(hole)

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

**I don't fully understand how to use the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext class. I don't understand what is the context? or why do I have to both addRect() and fillRect()? or what clip is?**

However, although those questions are important, my main concern is that the hole I have created is not transparent: it is white. I tried fixing it by doing this:

```
 context.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
```

However, that just didn't create any hole whatsoever. What do you guys recommend I do?

Comment: You should read the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066). While the code in that document is in Objective-C, all of the concepts and APIs are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `context.clear(CGRect)`

as is defined in documentation

> ```
> /* Clear `rect' (that is, set the region within the rect to transparent). */
>
> @available(iOS 2.0, *)
> public func clear(_ rect: CGRect)
> ```

this is how your code should be

```
let hole = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.clear(hole)

image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Why did you get rid of the context.clip(using: .evenOdd)?

Comment: @Pablo because is unnecessary in your problem, only with clear we can do the job

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: @Pablo from my answer,  /* Clear `rect' (that is, set the region within the rect to transparent). */

Comment: I meant what does clip() do, but I'll read more about it since I pretty much know nothing about that UIGraphics.

Comment: Hi, I try to use this sample code but I get nil when trying to unwrap : 
`let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!`
any ideas? . Thanks

Comment: @H.Epstein its seems that you don't have currentContext defined, where are you implementing that method? is a UIView subclass or any or you are subclassing any other class

Comment: I don't have it implemented yet , how should I do it? what I have is a UI image that I want to punch a rect hole in it.